# How can I open the Chrome browser in mobile mode using the Selenium webdriver for load testing in JMeter?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I want to open a URL in the Chrome browser, but in mobile mode during my load test in JMeter. I am using Selenium scripts. Below is my Selenium script

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium,org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) // Import Java Selenium packages
var Thr = JavaImporter(java.lang.Thread) // Import Thread sleep packages
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,30) // Import WebDriverWait Package

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('https://xyz=${__urlencode(${token})}');

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Below is the Java class I have created in `BeanShell` Preprocessor in `Jmeter` to use Chromeoptions to open Chrome in mobile mode, but I don't know how I can call it in `webdriver` above and I am doing it correctly or not:

```
public class page {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String device = "Samsung Galaxy S4";
        //options.ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.EnableMobileEmulation(device);
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274952/2104638

Answer (score 3):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
2. There is no `EnableMobileEmulation` function in [ChromeOptions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html), you should be using [`setExperimentalOption` instead](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setExperimentalOption-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

Example code for the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");

Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Galaxy S5");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
driver.get("http://example.com");
log.info(driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```